# Why did the inside change from AND to OR

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In the question that was posted two years ago (link provided) there is a solution that was provided by the opener. In this solution I was wondering why the inside propositional connectives changed from AND to OR. I understood that first the implication had to be changed, then it had to be distributed twice in order for it to be in proper CNF.

[Converting DNF to CNF and vice versa](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968848/converting-dnf-to-cnf-and-vice-versa/2965001#2965001)

Comment: *As explained in the post*, we have to use [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement)  : from $(¬P ∨ Q) ∧ (¬S ∨ R)$ to $((¬P ∨ Q) ∧ ¬S) ∨ ((¬P ∨ Q) ∧ R)$ using **Distributive law**. Then Distributivity again to get : $((¬P∧¬S) ∨ (Q∧¬S)) ∨ ((¬P∧R) ∨ (Q∧R))$

Comment: I got that part, I am talking about this part specifically: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhbhN.png